# How to retrieve id from mybatis insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I am using mybatis to insert records. I used on duplicate key update, while inserting i am able to retrieve dataId but while update mybatis does not retrieve dataId.

my mybatis code

```
<insert id="insertData" parameterType="objectDO"
    useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="dataId">
    INSERT INTO xyz (.....
    )
    VALUES
    (......
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    .....
```

What is the alternative for this to retrieve dataId irrespective if it is inserted or updated the record.

Comment: No, but assuming there's only a single unique key that's not the primary key, you can use that to retrieve the actual record that's been updated.

Comment: Finally i found that is the only possible solution. I implemented in similar lines. thanks for the affirmative answer.